# Printer DNP DS-RX1 doesn't print second file or page, end with error [Job N] Printer Status: Idle

Tags: printing

Freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 and usb photo printer Printer DNP DS-RX1 (cups + Gutenprint Printer Drivers), print fist page or file in any job and than finishes rest of job/s with error [Job N] Printer Status: Idle.
I printed from terminal with such command

lpr -P Photo_Printer3 Test.png Test2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to the driver developer - Solomon Peachy, he fixed that bug.

`git clone git://git.shaftnet.org/selphy_print.git
cd selphy_print
make && sudo make install`

By the way he wrote to me:

> One thing that I would strongly recommend is filing a Ubuntu bug to
>   request in the 14.04 LTS release they upgrade to gutenprint 5.2.10-final
>   (rather than -pre2).